How do I avoid drilling into live wires around a light switch?
I want to install a curtain holdback. There’s a light switch near the area where I want to install it. Which areas relative to the light switch are safe to drill holes into? I want to avoid damaging the electrical wiring when installing this curtain holdback.


Does the holdback come with screws?  If so, how long are they?

Original electrical boxes are typically mounted to a stud. If you can't determine whether there is a stud immediately to the right of the box with a stud finder or by knocking on the wall you can remove the coverplate and look. You can often see the adjacent stud between the box and the wall surface, through holes in the side of the box, or infer its location by the mounting nails passing through the box. You can also drill a small hole through the wall on either side of the box just deep enough to determine whether there is a stud behind it in a location that will be hidden by the coverplate.

At the location you are holding the holdback there are probably a set of studs and you will be able to screw into these solid wood members. Very unlikely to have wires in that location.
Most people use a stud finder to locate the edges of studs they want to screw into, but a lot can be learned by tapping the wall with a knuckle.
Mark holes where you want the holdback, then drill small holes there. The size would be the right size for "pilot" holes for screwing into studs. The hole closer to the door will almost certainly be into a stud and if you encounter a stud, keep drilling to the depth for the screws you have. If you do not encounter a stud use a drywall anchor as described below.
If the farther hole is just drywall, then stop drilling with the small drill when it emerges into empty space behind the drywall, and follow the directions for the drywall anchor you are going to use.
Most anchors require a certain size hole in the drywall. The type shown below in the other answer does not need a hole so if that is what you are using, then just put the tip into the small hole you drilled and follow directions. I have used that type of drywall anchor a number of times with good results.
If the drywall anchor needs a hole drilled, then change to the specified size drill for whatever drywall anchor you are going to use.  Drill this hole and stop as soon as the drill breaks through the drywall. If a wire would be there (unlikely), you will not have damaged it. At this point you could probe through the hole with a small dowel or a small screwdriver or a piece of wire coathanger to insure there is no wire. This is not really required, but cannot do any harm.
Insert a drywall anchor if necessary and screw the holdback into place.

There's a very high chance you have two wood studs starting where the blue line is in my picture, and extending 3 in to the left.   And a very high chance the cables for that switch go either up or down from it, and do not go through the studs because there is nowhere for them to go.
There's always a small risk you'll screw up. But here that risk is tiny. Drill small pilot holes, make sure you get into the wood stud, start with the one on the right.  If the left hand hole in your bracket is more than 3 inches from my blue line, drill a new hole that is less than 3 inches and use that instead.
There may only be one stud there, you'll know when the pilot drill gets through the plaster. Then you'll need to use a plug rather than a long wood screw.


Open the switch cover and look if any cables go to the right of it
If you do not find studs, I would recommend following anchors for drywall
pre-drill just a small hole than screw it in

found on

That position should have studs between the door and the switch box.  Drywall anchors will not work/go in.

Please provide required attribution link to the image in your answer.

Never use anchors for anything substantial when studs are available.
